# XMLStreamWriter exception: Attribute not associated with any element

Tags: java, xmlstreamwriter

I'm getting this exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Attribute not associated with any element
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at de.dhbw.horb.routePlanner.parser.GraphDataParser$2.run(GraphDataParser.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*
```

From my code below.
I just don't understand where it's comming from.

```
public void writeEdgeXML() throws XMLStreamException {

    final long[] idCount = new long[1];

    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

    try {
        final XMLStreamWriter writer = factory
                .createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(
                        GraphDataConstants.CONST_XML_EDGE), "UTF-8");

        writer.writeStartDocument("UTF-8", "1.0");

        while (graphSR.hasNext()) {
            if (graphSR.nextStartElement() && graphSR.isWay()) {

                final Way nextWay = getWay(null);

                Controller.executor.getExecutor().submit(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        while (nextWay != null && nextWay.hasEdge()) {

                            try {
                                idCount[0]++;
                                Edge e = nextWay.removeFirstEdge();
                                writer.writeStartElement(GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE);
                                writer.writeAttribute(
                                        GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE_ID,
                                        String.valueOf(idCount[0]));
                                writer.writeEmptyElement(GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE_NODE);
                                writer.writeAttribute(
                                        GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE_ID,
                                        String.valueOf(e.getStartNode()
                                                .getID()));
                                writer.writeAttribute(
                                        GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE_LATITUDE,
                                        String.valueOf(e.getStartNode()
                                                .getLatitude()));
                                writer.writeAttribute(
                                        GraphDataConstants.CONST_EDGE_LONGITUDE,
                                        String.valueOf(e.getStartNode()
                                                .getLongitude()));                                  

                                writer.writeEndElement();
                                writer.flush();

                            } catch  (XMLStreamException e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: at de.dhbw.horb.routePlanner.parser.GraphDataParser$2.run(GraphDataParser.java:136)

Comment: You probably cannot write an attribute after `writeEmptyElement`.  Are the attributes supposed to go on the empty element or the enclosing element?

Comment: @rahul pasricha::D thanks for telling me what i can read in the exception. I can understand exceptions. The problem is, this one makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JimGarrison: It should look like this: <edge id="1"><node id="324" lat="59.3" lon="6.0"/><node id="325" lat="59.4" lon="6.1"/></edge>

Comment: I just tried it... my earlier comment was incorrect, you can add attributes to an empty element.

Comment: You are printing the stack trace on exception and then continuing... is there another exception before this one?

Comment: @JimGarrison: No. Certainly Ian Roberts is right (answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLStreamWriter` is not thread safe.

You're creating a single `XMLStreamWriter` and then trying to use it to write elements in multiple threads at once.  This is not guaranteed to work at all, and if it does the elements and attributes you create won't necessarily end up where you expected them.  I suspect the error is down to a race condition along the lines of

```
Thread 1             Thread 2
--------             --------
1) emptyElement
2) attribute
                     3) emptyElement
4) endElement
                     5) attribute (BANG!)
```

You need to serialize all the XML writing into a single thread.

Comment: That is my assumption too. But how to serialize to a single thread? Doesn't that slow it down?

Comment: @besnep you don't have a choice really.  If `removeFirstEdge` were an expensive operation then it might make sense to have multiple threads and just synchronize the XML writing bit from the start to the end of the edge element, but that bit will definitely have to be single threaded.  If `removeFirstEdge` is cheap then you might as well single thread the whole thing and do away with the context switching overhead.